# How to save the instance of singleton class

Tags: php, jquery

I made a singleton class calendar that I initialized in the index.php file.

When I try to get a previous or next month using the jquery .ajax post I realize that my singleton object gets destroyed and initialized again using private constructor.

How to keep the first instance of singleton until the closure of the page so I can move through calendar? Is there a way to stop destruction of singleton instance?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP an object's lifecycle is entirely within the request - it will not persist values like you would see in other languages like Java. This means that your singleton class will be instantiated on every request, but within that request you can only have one instance of it.

The reason for this is that PHP is a scripting language - everything is thrown away when the script execution completes.

If you want to share data between requests you will need to use something like a caching layer (APC, Memcached, etc), or even write to the Session or disk.